# Docker not reload nodejs app even I use nodemon?

Tags: node.js, express, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem which it took my two days and still not find any solution. I am developing an express app with docker but when make code changes docker not reload the app. I have to docker-compose down and up to see the changes. I search a lot on the internet but can't find any solution to fit my problem.

I will very grateful if you help me. Thanks a lot.

My docker directory like this:

```
/api
   Dockerfile
/mongo
   Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

Here is my /api/Dockerfile  code

```
FROM node:latest

RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Here is my compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    container_name: ats-express
    build: ./api
    volumes:
      - ../ats-api:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo

    restart: always
```

and here is my npm start script in package.json at express-api

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just so happened to me before, and my way of resolving this issue is to add a `--legacy-watch` flag to the nodemon command

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --legacy-watch ./bin/www"
}
```

Comment: It works for me too. Thank you so much for help. I  appreciated

Comment: Mine:
"scripts": {

        "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch  src/app.ts",
}

doesn't work

Comment: @M.Abulsoud Can you confirm that you are using Docker's volume to mount your data into your container